# Error: cannot cast type record to numeric Postgresql

Tags: sql, casting, record, numeric

I'm trying to round out a record so it doesn't have so many decimals

```
SELECT round(yr_amount::numeric, 0) yr_amount

FROM table
```

Comment: Can you share your table's DDL? What RDBMS are you using (looks like postgres)?

Comment: ***Any*** of the table values have a $ , Y or some non integer, decimal value?

Comment: It has a negative sign. Let me put it to postgres.

Comment: Yes @xQbert It has a () on it.

Comment: I would think that's the problem then.  These would need to be stripped before the round would work as the DB is implicitly trying to convert a text field to numeric and failing.  So either sanitize the data so that the implicit conversions can work (Prevention), manage possible non-numeric values in yr_amount when doing the round (Error handle), or exclude non-numeric values from the analysis (ignore/exclude).